# Issue in using snappy with avro in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, avro, snappy

I am reading the .gz file and converting to AVRO format. When I was using the `codec='deflate'`. It is working fine. i.e., I was able to convert to avro format. When I use `codec='snappy'` it is throwing an error stating below:

```
raise DataFileException("Unknown codec: %r" % codec)
avro.datafile.DataFileException: Unknown codec: 'snappy'
```

with deflate --> working fine

```
writer = DataFileWriter(open(avro_file, "wb"), DatumWriter(), schema, codec='deflate')
```

with snappy --> throwing an error

```
writer = DataFileWriter(open(avro_file, "wb"), DatumWriter(), schema, codec = "snappy")
```

a quick response would be a great help.

Thanks.

.
.

Comment: Kindly provide you code.

Answer (score 4):

from avro/datafile.py

```
try:
  import snappy
  has_snappy = True
except ImportError:
  has_snappy = False

...

# Codecs supported by container files:
VALID_CODECS = frozenset(['null', 'deflate'])
if has_snappy:
  VALID_CODECS = frozenset.union(VALID_CODECS, ['snappy'])
```

so you have to install python-snappy lib